# c++ class function inside call to another class function

Tags: c++, function, class

I am currently working towards my Tower Defence game with c++ and sfml 2.3 with   3 classes

fragments of my code in my main cpp file

problem: when RangeCollision() is called in tower.h class i want to send some variables over to different class (mobs class) to function ReduceMinionHealth and let it decrease health of minions

```
    #include <Defines.h> //defining bunch of includes and defines

    #include "Mobs.h"
    #include "Towers.h"
    #include "MainClass.h"
    int main() {
    MainClass* mainObj = new MainClass();
    TowerClass* towerObj = new TowerClass();
    MobsClass* mobsObj = new MobsClass();
    //keeps checking for actions and detecting clicks
    towerObj->BulletCollision(mobsObj->Mob1v, speedMultiplier); //detects when bullet reached minion
    if (mainObj->waveStarted) mobsObj->MobPathing(speedMultiplier); //minions moving their path
    //drawing sprites
    return(0);
    }
```

MainClass.h file

```
#ifndef MainClass_h
#define MainClass_h

#include "Defines.h"

class MainClass {
    static int map[];
public:
    static int coins, lives;
    static bool waveStarted;

    MainClass::MainClass() {
        //constructor loading some stuff
    }
//bunch of functions
```

};

tower.h class file

```
#ifndef Towers_h
#define Towers_h

#include <Defines.h>
#include "MainClass.h"

class TowerClass: public MainClass {
private:
    vector<int> towerDmg;
    vector<int> towerCost;
    vector<float> towerRange;
public:
    bool Clicked;
    float dx, dy, magnitude;
    //loading textures and other variables

typedef struct {
    //sprites, tower params
    vector<Sprite> bullet;
    vector<int> shootAt;
}towerParamStruct;

vector<towerParamStruct> TowerParam;

TowerClass::TowerClass() {
//constructor
}

void BulletCollision(vector<Sprite> &Mob1v, float speedMultiplier) {
     //doing some stuff and at some point calling 
     MobsClass::MinionHealthReduce(int i, double DamageDealt) //gives me error
}
};
```

mobs.h class below

```
#ifndef Mobs_h
#define Mobs_h

#include "Defines.h"
#include "MainClass.h"

class MobsClass: public MainClass {
    private:
        vector<double> *Health, *levelHealth;
        vector<int> *levelMobsCount, *levelCoins;
    public:
    Sprite Mob1;
    vector<Sprite> Mob1v;

    MobsClass::MobsClass() {
    //constructor which prepares for first wave
    }

    void MinionHealthReduce(int i, double DamageDealt) {
        if (Health->at(i) > 0) {
            //recalculating hp bar
            Health->at(i) = Health->at(i) - DamageDealt;
        }
        if (Health->at(i) <= 0) {
            //add coins because u killed minion
            //destroys minion
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Please be more specific.

Comment: `TowerClass::MinionHealthReduce(int i, double DamageDealt)` probably needs an instance to be called with, unless it's a `static` class member of `TowerClass`.

Comment: i want from inside tower class function RangeCollision() for it to send some variables to mobs class function ReduceMinionHealth() and decrease minions health inside it

Comment: That function you are trying to call is a member of `MobsClass` not `TowerClass` so unless its a static member of `MobsClass` you cannot call it like that. And even if it was you would need to call it as `MobsClass::MinionHealthReduce()`

Comment: @mathematician1975 sorry i edited it and it suppost to be MobsClass, yes. I have tried to create and instance but isn't there anything more to it than just creating static variables?

Comment: I'm still a novice, at C++ (not that I can code in any other language), but I think I know where the problem is: what you're doing inside `BulletCollision` is nothing like calling the method of an external object. What you have to do, instead, is to pass the `mobsObj` object into `BulletCollision` as a pointer. This way you'll be able to put your hands on the actual object, and its `health` method will respond properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I see your errors, in the following line:

`MobsClass::MinionHealthReduce(int i, double DamageDealt)`

3 errors I can see:

1. No semicolon
2. Needs to be called using an object
3. Cannot be called with `(int i, double DamageDealt)`

Fixed version:

```
MobsClass* mobsObj = new MobsClass();
mobsObj.MinionHealthReduce(i, DamageDealt);
```

I believe this should solve your problem, but I am not quite sure what exactly the problem is.
If it is something about passing variables, remember to pass them by reference.

Edit: I am trying to get at what Zehryo Karham was saying in the comments. I just read the comments.